# Latexmk pvc inactivity timeout

Tags: latexmk

I'm using latexmk with the continuous preview option (-pvc) to compile my papers. However, when I'm done editing, it just keeps watching the files until I stop it manually (this produces problems e.g. when my Dropbox coauthors start editing the files). Is there a way for me to make it stop automatically after, say, 30 minutes of inactivity?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) not build in no. You can ask the author to add this feature.

Comment: I'll add this feature to the next version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optional timeout in -pvc mode is provided in the latest version of `latexmk` v. 4.55.  See the documentation for the -pvctimeout, -pvctimeout-, and -pvctimeoutmins options, and the corresponding configuration variables $pvc_timeout and $pvc_timeout_mins.